# 3d plot to access distribution of variables in space

Tags: r, 3d, space, scatter-plot

I want to generate a plot in which I'm capable of visualising the distribution of a given variable in space.

Let's say I want to know how the values of frequency bandwidth (Hz) of a bird's song are spread in space.

I tried with `scatterplot3d`. But I'm think this is not right.

```
x<-a vector with easting coordinates
y<-a vector with northing coordinates
z<-a vector with the bandwidth values (in Hz)
```

Then I do:

```
scatterplot3d(x,y,z)
```

Should "z" be a coordinate or can I use it as a vector of values of a given variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out `persp`too.

Comment: And `lattice` functions `wireframe` and `cloud`.  You should be able to use `z` as a vector, yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried both suggestions, still didn't succeeded in my attempt to plot something like desired. I couldn't properly understand the arguments of those functions. As I said, I would like to use: x<-Data$Easting, y<-Data$Northing, z<-Data$Bwidth. Then run something like cloud(x,y,z)

Comment: Frequency of a birdcall is spread in **time**, not space.  But anyway, you should check out the `seewave` package which has some excellent graphics for displaying frequency and amplitude vs. time, and waterfall plots, and more. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of one of the graph tools in this package)

Comment: Hi, I'm familiar to seewave. And it's a great package. What I meant is that I want to visualize the distribution of the values I extracted from sonograms in space. For example: birds singing at higher pitch are geographically closer to each other. I want to plot the values of frequencies in space to check if this statement is true.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Well, first, play w/ the recommended plotting functions until you're comfortable with the ways to assign x,y,z coordinates.  As an alternative, consider a 2D plot with either colorscale or bubble-size representing the frequency band at each x-y location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with scatterplot3d.

```
   scatterplot3d(Hypo$Easting,Hypo$Northing,Hypo$Song_Dur,angle=118,color="red",pch=16,highlight.3d=TRUE,xlab="Easting",ylab="Northing",type="h",lwd=1)
```

Where Hypo$Easting==x, Hypo$Northing==y and Hypo$Song_Dur==z(variable).